# NetLogo: Finding out all turtles linked to each other and assigning them to a group id

Tags: netlogo

I have searched all topics for the last week and haven't be able to yet find a solution to my problem. The scenario is as follows:

1. I have various groups of turtles that are linked to each other
2. I would like to assign a group name or id to each group

In order to do the above, I am thinking that I need a procedure that will find out the id of a turtle and then tell me to which other turtles this particular turtle is linked to. So for example I have a group of 4 turtles, all linked to each other. Their ids are 1, 2, 3, 4. Now I would like to get a list of each turtle, which also tells me to whom it is linked to. Here an example list:

```
Turtle 1 -> Linked to Turtle 2, 3 and 4
Turtle 2 -> Linked to Turtle 1, 3 and 4
...
Turtle 4 -> Linked to Turtle 1, 2 and 3
```

Once I now which this (although maybe there is a much easier way). I could assign a group id to these 4 turtles.

Any feedback / help very much appreciated.

Here is part of the code:

```
to go
    ask turtles [    
      set neighbours turtle-set turtles in-radius neighbourhood
      set turtle-dim-similar min-one-of other neighbours [myfunc myself self]
      create-link-with turtle-dim-similar  
    ]

   set beasts sort-by [[who] of ?1 < [who] of ?2] turtles 
   foreach beasts [ 
       ask ? [ ;; each agent undertakes the list of commands 
           set closest sort [link-neighbors] of turtle who 
           print (word "id:" who " ; val1:" value1 " ; val2:" value2 " ; closest:" closest) 
       ] 
   ]
 end
```

Comment: Out-link-neighbors gives the set of turtles linked to.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I have tried using out-link-neighbours and in various variations, but I keep getting a "breed" error. I have not defined any breeds in the model, because I don't need them. Will post some sample code later ...

Comment: Is it "LINKS is a undirected breed"? If so try link-neighbors or make sure you are using "create-link-with" to make them.

Comment: Hi King-Ink, yes that it exactly and I am using "create-link-with" 

Here is a bit of code where I am trying to implement that:

`set beasts sort-by [[who] of ?1 < [who] of ?2] turtles`
 
`foreach beasts [`
    `ask ? [ ;; each agent undertakes the list of commands`   
     `set closest sort [link-neighbors] of turtle who` 
     `print (word "id:" who " ; val1:" value1 " ; val2:" value2 " ; closest:" closest)`   
    `]`
`]`

Comment: Ps. i have also tried using my-links, and have been able to get the turtle ids of 2 turtles that are linked to a particular turtle, but just not how the links continue. So for example Turtle 2 has links to turtle 1 and 3, but what I want to know is how that goes on because Turtle 3 is linked to Turtle 4, so what I wanted was a list of ALL turtles linked to each other .. eg. the print out should tell me that Turtle 2 is linked to 1, 2 and 3. :)

Comment: I think i got it. I will put my answer in a answer. You should add your code to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using directed links i.e. links created with create-link-to, create-link-from, create-links-to or create-links-from than out-link-neighbors is what you are looking for. It reports a set of the  turtles linked to.

If you are using un-directed links, ones created with create-link-with or create-links-with , use link-neighbors.

This solves the first part of the problem for the second half use recursion.

```
Turtles-own[group-id]
To id [tag]
     Set group-id tag
     Ask link-neighbors with[Group-id != tag]
[Id tag]
  End
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) that is very helpful. If have implemented that now in my code and from what I understand this assigns a group-id to each turtle and now I need to find a way to recurse it. This is were I have been really stuck for a while, (sorry, I do feel rather stupid. I know this should be my part)

Comment: Just ask one of the turtles to run id thus.    Ask turtle 1 [id 1]